# Parsing JSON in PHP with encrypted values

Tags: php, json

We receive a JSON string which need to be decoded and added to the respective table(s).  The string that we receive is

```
 {"root":[
    {"regstatus":"M","mobilenumber":"8888","updateon":1611920526063,
     "mobileregistrationpk":"1234","keyvalue":null,"sentstatus":"N",
     "password":"#Î@Í%Ì","fullname":"siva"
    },
    {"regstatus":"M","mobilenumber":"123","updateon":1611930204138,
     "mobileregistrationpk":"ed6bef4700dc7a4d1448a1ce862cef54",
     "keyvalue":null,"sentstatus":"N","password":"#Î@Í%Ì","fullname":"praveen"
    }
]}
```

The above string is assigned to a variable $json.

```
$someArray = json_decode($json, true)  -> Returns NULL
```

Is it because of password field that contains encrypted value ?   In that case how to deal with this ?

How to parse this JSON ?  We tried with

```
foreach ($someArray as $mydata) {
       echo $someArray->root;
}

for each ($someArray as $mydata) {
     for each ($mydata as $one)
         echo $one->root;
     }
}
```

Nothing works..

We need your help

1. To process the JSON with the encrypted value.
2. And code to parse this JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `var_dump(`[`json_last_error_msg`](https://www.php.net/json-last-error-msg)`())` to show what PHP doesn't like about the input? Encrypted or not, your input should be valid JSON and if it isn't then the data source needs to be fixed, not your decoding of it.

Comment: Your code looks ok. I can not reproduce the issue. https://phpize.online/?phpses=27a47aa9816b66e0466a234af6f2527c&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Yes... when you copy-paste the visible characters of an encrypted string into a UTF-8 context, you get a valid UTF-8 string. But that's not what the code is dealing with.

Comment: try it before speculating http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56cddfec795a2923064b7ee8f495d6d2b1d6d1c6

Comment: Error returned by json_last_error()
- Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
Tried saving the file in UTF-8 format in Notepad++.  Attached the php file below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
  //Loop through Array
  //$someJSON ='[{"name":"Jonathan Suh","gender":"male"},{"name":"William Philbin","gender":"male"},{"name":"Allison McKinnery","gender":"female"}]';
  //$someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
  //foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
  //  echo $value["name"] . ", " . $value["gender"] . "<br>";
  //}
  
  $someJSON = '{"root":[{"regstatus":"M","mobilenumber":"8888","updateon":1611920526063,"mobileregistrationpk":"1234","keyvalue":null,"sentstatus":"N","password":"#΀̢ͥ,"fullname":"siva"},{"regstatus":"M","mobilenumber":"123","updateon":1611930204138,"mobileregistrationpk":"ed6bef4700dc7a4d1448a1ce862cef54","keyvalue":null,"sentstatus":"N","password":"#΀̢ͥ,"fullname":"praveen"}]}';
  $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
  if (is_array($someArray)) {
      echo "Array <br>";
  }
  var_dump($someArray);
?>
```

In the above code var_dump($someArray) returns NULL when executed in my local Apache Web server.

Tried saving the php file with UTF-8 encoding.  Still the same result.

Update:

Sorry.  The encrypted characters got corrupted while copying from the original source.    I'll check in the original source files for those errors and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry.  Seems the encrypted characters got corrupted or modified while copying from the original source file.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in the question **is** [valid](https://jsonlint.com) ...while the one in your answer lacks `,"` twice.

And if encoding fails, just pass a byte or hexadecimal representation of these possibly out-of-range characters (which one may or may not be able to represent as UTF-8). I mean, there is a realistic chance, that one of the characters contained may break the syntax - which decimal numbers or hexadecimal `00` until `FF` would reliably prevent, without having to mind about special cases.
This approach would add a few bytes to the overall payload - but you'd be on the safe side.

Have you considered the possibility, that the encryption's output may contain `"` or `\` ?

Answer (score -2):

The JSON you provided is valid. I've tried it myself:

```
$json = '{"root":[{"regstatus":"M","mobilenumber":"8888","updateon":1611920526063,"mobileregistrationpk":"1234","keyvalue":null,"sentstatus":"N","password":"#Î@Í%Ì","fullname":"siva"},{"regstatus":"M","mobilenumber":"123","updateon":1611930204138,"mobileregistrationpk":"ed6bef4700dc7a4d1448a1ce862cef54","keyvalue":null,"sentstatus":"N","password":"#Î@Í%Ì","fullname":"praveen"}]}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($array);
```

result as

```
Array
(
    [root] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [regstatus] => M
                    [mobilenumber] => 8888
                    [updateon] => 1611920526063
                    [mobileregistrationpk] => 1234
                    [keyvalue] => 
                    [sentstatus] => N
                    [password] => #Î@Í%Ì
                    [fullname] => siva
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [regstatus] => M
                    [mobilenumber] => 123
                    [updateon] => 1611930204138
                    [mobileregistrationpk] => ed6bef4700dc7a4d1448a1ce862cef54
                    [keyvalue] => 
                    [sentstatus] => N
                    [password] => #Î@Í%Ì
                    [fullname] => praveen
                )

        )

)
```

So problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: And yet it clearly isn't working or else OP wouldn't be here.